# CSLA Framework CanReadProperty

Tags: c#, csla

In the [CSLA.NET](https://cslanet.com) Framework, what is the purpose of the **CanReadProperty** method?

Answer (score 3):

It's a method that allows to check whether it is allowed to read a certain property:

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns <see langword="true" /> if the user is allowed to read the
/// calling property.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="property">Property to check.</param>
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
public virtual bool CanReadProperty(Csla.Core.IPropertyInfo property)
{
  bool result = true;

  VerifyAuthorizationCache();

  if (!_readResultCache.TryGetValue(property.Name, out result))
  {
    result = BusinessRules.HasPermission(AuthorizationActions.ReadProperty, property);
    // store value in cache
    _readResultCache[property.Name] = result;
  }

  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically it allows you to have different access permissions for individual properties on a business object.

Answer (score 0):

It gives specific access permission to the Data contract Properties.